# ClickOnce application identity and WinForms-WPF migration

Tags: wpf, winforms, migration, clickonce

I'd like to migrate one of the applications I maintain from Windows Forms to WPF.

The application already has WPF controls hosted in ElementHost, and I'd like to switch to a WPF application in which I may have WindowsFormsHost controls (ultimately it should become a 100% WPF application).

The application is published using ClickOnce. If I change the project type to WPF, and republish to the same target, is it going to break the application's identity and prevent users from receiving the upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winformsue/archive/2006/04/20/580223.aspx):

> What is a ClickOnce Identity? The identity of a ClickOnce application
>   is expressed by all of the properties (minus version) of the
>   applicationIdentity element in the deployment manifest:
>
> - Application name (specified as "Product Name" in Visual Studio)
> - Public key token
> - Language
> - Processor architecture
>
> Why Should I Care? **If two ClickOnce
>   deployments have an applicationIdentity element with all four of these
>   attributes in common, then they are deploying the same application
>   regardless of the location of the deployments.**

I think this fairly clearly states "No".

[Link to another SO question discussing this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836154/one-click-application-moving-from-winforms-to-wpf)

Comment: Thanks for the reply; in my case none of these changes so why should the identity change?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Answered: "Will it be the same application?" instead of "Will it break" for some reason.  You should be good to go.

Comment: oops sorry about that, (it was my first bounty...). Thanks.